# Retain items in nested list only if present in X other sublists

Tags: python

I have a nested list like the following:

```
test = [['hello', 'hola'], ['hello, 'bonjour', 'hola'], ['hello', 'ciao', 'namaste'], ['hola', 'ciao'], ['hola', 'ciao], ['namaste', 'bonjour', 'bonjour']]
```

I am interested in removing all elements from each sublist if it is not present in at least X sublists total (shared words with threshold for definition of sharing). For this example if we set X = 3, only the values 'hello' and 'hola' and 'ciao' would remain in any list, yielding:

```
shared = [['hello', 'hola'], ['hello, 'hola'], ['hello', 'ciao'], ['hola', 'ciao'], ['hola', 'ciao], []]
```

I also want another list with the exact inverse logic, retaining values that are present in less than X sublists total, yielding the removal of  'hello' and 'hola' and 'ciao' from all lists.

How can this be done? I would put some code here but am lost with writing the login in Python as a beginner.

Thanks,
Jack

EDIT: Note that bonjour shows up 3 times, but only in two sublists, so it is not considered shared.

Comment: Are there any instances where multiple of the same word can be in a sublist?

Comment: You could consider flattening the list and using the `collections.Counter` class to get the counts of each element.

Comment: @user3483203 Yes this is a possibility. Sorry I didn't include it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the count of each word using **`collections.Counter`** on a flattened list, using a set to ignore repeated values in a single sublist:

```
appearances = Counter(word for sub in arr for word in set(sub))
# Counter({'hola': 4, 'hello': 3, 'ciao': 3, 'bonjour': 2, 'namaste': 2})
```

Next, use a list comprehension and dictionary lookup (an O(1) operation) to return only words that appear in enough sublists:

```
[[word for word in sub if appearances[word] >= threshold] for sub in arr]
```

Put it all together in a simple function and return your desired result:

```
from collections import Counter

def threshold_filter(arr, threshold):
  appearances = Counter(word for sub in arr for word in set(sub))

  return [
    [word for word in sub if appearances[word] >= threshold] 
    for sub in arr
  ]

print(threshold_filter(test, 3))

# Result 
[['hello', 'hola'], ['hello', 'hola'], ['hello', 'ciao'], ['hola', 'ciao'], ['hola', 'ciao'], []]
```